# How are emojis inserted into a Docusaurus webpage?

Tags: emoji, docusaurus

I'm building a website with [Docusaurus V2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/introduction).

Does anyone know how the small icons (e.g. correct mark, wrong mark) are inserted in their document.

Additionally, where could we see the Docusaurus files of their website (rather than the built files), so that we could learn?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emojis are actually unicode. Two ways to "type" emojis:

- Activate your emoji keyboard and start typing them. This is OS-specific and you can google for the instructions
- Go to an emoji website such as [getemoji.com](https://getemoji.com) and copy/paste them